# Selenium HREF Java

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, href

I am trying to 'click' on the href link 'cc.aspx?SystemId=...' in the HTML code below but whatever i tried is not working.
The link does not open a new page but update the contents of the same URL page as when I click on this link, the URL is the same but a frame is loaded with new informations.

When I inspect the element:
The Path is:  //*[@id="Matrix-tab"]
The Full Path is:  /html/body/form[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/nav/a[2]

PS: This application requires a Login and Password so for every new connection, the following parameters are variables (Keys) :SystemID, RessourceID and SessionID. These variables are in the href..
I have no problem to retreive these.

```
<nav class="plm-tabs-primary nav nav-pills" id="myTab">  

    <a id="Props1-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center active Props" href="" plm-data-contentinframe="false" data-target="#Props1">Form</a>

    <a id="Matrix-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center Matrix " href="cc.aspx?SystemId={sy}&amp;ResourceId={re}&amp;SessionId={se}&amp;IsInFrame=1&amp;Entity=Part&amp;EntityDefGUID=OTD;OT_DIST_MATRIX&amp;PartGUID=OTI;OT_DIST_MATRIX;project&amp;WithNavigBar=0" plm-data-contentinframe="true" data-target="#Matrix">Matrix</a>

</nav>
```

If someone could direct me in the good direction...
Thanks

I have tried so many different ways that I am very confused now.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.id, 'Matrix-tab'))).click()
```

Comment: Please share a link to the page your working on. We can't guess what going on there

Comment: Why do you think that the clicking does not work?